# Do we really need "online" in tags on a web applications site?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are lots of tags like "online-security" and "online-storage" showing up. Do we really need "online" - isn't that implied?

Comment: No, no you don't need that. I'd just retag them.

Comment: @Kinopiko: I did. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree we don't need the tag [online] -- it seems redundant to me, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure. I just saw this question after I posted [a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/a-web-app-for-easily-creating-and-maintaining-online-shops) which I tagged [online-shop].

I think just [shop] or [shopping] don't really cut it.

[shopping-cart] maybe? But that only covers part of what I want.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not? What kind of shop will it be on a "web apps" Q&A site? Using "online" to shop on WebApps feels like adding "programming" to the C# tag on StackOverflow - completely redundant.