# Burninate [storage] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

**UPDATE**: As of just now, storage is not in use.
... and it was only afterwards I saw [Do we really need "online" in tags on a web applications site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/do-we-really-need-online-in-tags-on-a-web-applications-site)

---

This follows on from [Please make [storage] and [image-storage] synonyms of [online-storage]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/please-make-storage-and-image-storage-synonyms-of-online-storage) where the suitability of [storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) was questioned.

The tag has <strike>14</strike> 4 or maybe <strike>10</strike> <strike>9</strike> 5 Open Qs and no followers. Its Usage guide is:

> Commonly refers to computer components and recording media that retain digital data.

[Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) provided criteria for burnination, summarised as:

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is
>      applied?
> 2. Is it unambiguous?
> 3. Is the concept described even on-topic for the
>          site?
> 4. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> 5. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

To which the answers for [storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) seem to me to be, in order: Not necessarily, No , Could be, Yes, No. This based on current usage and the answers might differ if some tags were changed to more appropriate ones.

Since doubt about the value of retaining the tag has been raised, my Q is:

To keep or not to keep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it as a synonym of [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage). If you participate on this tag and have a 5 score on it, please consider to vote for this at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/online-storage/synonyms

Comment: @pnuts: Too bad, but thanks anyway.